DNS not working when transparent proxy is active
I started a ShadowSocks(Socks5) tproxy and configured iptables to route all the traffic towards it. It is working and listenning to traffic, I can access webpages by directly typing in the IP address; however it's not resolving any domain/DNS requests.
I tested the network by the following commands, which supposably means that the network is working and it's just the dns not working. Note that everything is perfectly fine if I just use the normal proxy of ShadowSocks.

I started the tproxy with this command model
ss-redir -s ServerIP -p ServerPort -m EncryptionMethod -k MyPasswd -b 127.0.0.1 -l 60080 --no-delay -u -T -v

and I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 Noble on gen 6+ kernel.

I tested the network with
$ nc -vz 172.217.163.46 80
Connection to 172.217.163.46 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!

$ nc -vz 172.217.163.46 443
Connection to 172.217.163.46 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!

$ nc -v -u 127.0.0.1 60080
Connection to 127.0.0.1 60080 port [udp/*] succeeded!

$ nc -zvu 8.8.8.8 53
Connection to 8.8.8.8 53 port [udp/domain] succeeded!

$ wget 172.217.163.46
--2024-11-06 18:05:45--  http://172.217.163.46/
Connecting to 172.217.163.46:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2024-11-06 18:05:45--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.google.com’

$ dig google.com @1.1.1.1
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: timed out



Here is the iptables config
##################### SSREDIR #####################
iptables -t mangle -N SSREDIR

# connection-mark -> packet-mark
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -m mark --mark 0x2333 -j RETURN

# please modify MyIP, MyPort, etc.
# ignore traffic sent to ss-server
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -p tcp -d 120.233.31.53 --dport 26262 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -p udp -d 120.233.31.53 --dport 26262 -j RETURN

# ignore traffic sent to reserved addresses
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 0.0.0.0/8          -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 10.0.0.0/8         -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 100.64.0.0/10      -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 127.0.0.0/8        -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 169.254.0.0/16     -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 172.16.0.0/12      -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 192.0.0.0/24       -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 192.0.2.0/24       -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 192.88.99.0/24     -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 192.168.0.0/16     -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 198.18.0.0/15      -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 198.51.100.0/24    -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 203.0.113.0/24     -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 224.0.0.0/4        -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 240.0.0.0/4        -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN

# mark the first packet of the connection
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -p tcp --syn                      -j MARK --set-mark 0x2333
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j MARK --set-mark 0x2333

# packet-mark -> connection-mark
iptables -t mangle -A SSREDIR -j CONNMARK --save-mark

##################### OUTPUT #####################
# proxy the outgoing traffic from this machine
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL ! --dst-type LOCAL -j SSREDIR
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL ! --dst-type LOCAL -j SSREDIR

##################### PREROUTING #####################
# proxy traffic passing through this machine (other->other)
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m addrtype ! --src-type LOCAL ! --dst-type LOCAL -j SSREDIR
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -m addrtype ! --src-type LOCAL ! --dst-type LOCAL -j SSREDIR

# hand over the marked package to TPROXY for processing
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m mark --mark 0x2333 -j TPROXY --on-ip 127.0.0.1 --on-port 60080
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -m mark --mark 0x2333 -j TPROXY --on-ip 127.0.0.1 --on-port 60080

ip route add local default dev lo table 100
ip rule  add fwmark 0x2333        table 100
ip rule  del   table 100 &>/dev/null
ip route flush table 100 &>/dev/null



Then I tried the NAT method, and not just it didn't work, it basically did nothing, every traffic isn't routed and it's not really doing anything
# Create new chain
iptables -t nat -N SHADOWSOCKS
iptables -t mangle -N SHADOWSOCKS

# Ignore your shadowsocks server's addresses
# It's very IMPORTANT, just be careful.
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d ServerIP -j RETURN

# Ignore LANs and any other addresses you'd like to bypass the proxy
# See Wikipedia and RFC5735 for full list of reserved networks.
# See ashi009/bestroutetb for a highly optimized CHN route list.
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN

# Anything else should be redirected to shadowsocks's local port
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345

# Add any UDP rules
ip route add local default dev lo table 100
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
iptables -t mangle -A SHADOWSOCKS -p udp --dport 53 -j TPROXY --on-port 12345 --tproxy-mark 0x01/0x01

# Apply the rules
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j SHADOWSOCKS
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j SHADOWSOCKS

# Start the shadowsocks-redir
ss-redir -s SeverIP -p SeverPort -m chacha20-ietf-poly1305 -k 6d2b5b66-0d3f-4189-a547-501eb658879a -b 127.0.0.1 -l 12345 --no-delay -v -u T </dev/null &>>/var/log/ss-redir.log &


It seems that ss-redir requires using -t nat. From the man page (https://manpages.org/shadowsocks-libev/8) "While ss-local(1) works as a standard socks5 proxy, ss-redir(1) works as a transparent proxy and requires netfilter's NAT module. For more information, check out the example section."

I did put the NAT rules, it displayed them in the post.

The example in the man pages uses -t nat, not -t mangle, e.g. iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN. More in the example in the man pages.

I thought nat is a type of mangle? ss-redir github page The github page suggested the method I use, do you think it will be a problem?

Thanks for the advice, I just tried the NAT method from the link you gived, turns out the NAT didn't do anything for some reason, it didn't do any rerouting and all my network is the same as before doing the NAT thing

I just tried that and it didn't do anything, like the NAT didn't effect my system in anyway posible. All the packages were going just like before I set NAT, it's not even routing to the proxy server

Check if ss-server supports UDP. It should have "mode":"tcp_and_udp" in the config file or -u as an option when started.

unfortunately I don't have access to the config of the server, is there anyway I can test if it's support udp?

try nc -v -u -z -w 3 ServerIP ServerPort. It should return Connection to ServerIP ServerPort [udp/*] succeeded!

yes, it did, do I suppose it's not a udp not supported error?
